# Displaying SQL query result from user input via wpdb

Tags: php, wpdb, code

I'm a bit stuck with one of my task which is to require a user input for an 'ID no' and it shall go through a table in my WP and display the result on the same page (after hitting Submit).

I'm currently using the Code Snippets plugin to insert this PHP code into one of my WP page. However, as of now, when I input a valid IC/ID no. into the input field, it doesn't seem to return anything.

Am I doing something wrong on the form part? Please enlighten. Thanks!

```php
<?php

$name=$_POST["ICNo"];

global $wpdb;
$resultsap = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `wp_apelc_users` WHERE `icno` = .$name.');
foreach($resultsap as $row) {
    echo 'Name: '.$row->name.', Status: '.$row->status.'<br/>';
}

?>

<form method="post">
  <div>
    Your IC No: <input type="text" name="ICNo">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: FYI, the table and columns are valid. If I omit the form part and only display the query, it works.

Comment: That `.$name.` is invalid, and you're not using double quotes (`"`), and you should use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/).

Comment: Thanks Sally, do you know what I should use in the query that defines 'an input from the user'? So meaning to say, I should write something like ".$name." ?

Comment: Yes, that would work. But once again, I highly suggest you to use `$wpdb->prepare()` to avoid SQL injections (and other security issues) - `$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_apelc_users WHERE icno = %s", $name ) )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use this snippet it works

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["ICNo"])) {
global $wpdb;
$name = $_POST["ICNo"];
 $resultsap = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_apelc_users WHERE icno = %s", $name ) );
foreach ($resultsap as $row) {
echo 'Name: ' . $row->name;
}
}
?>
<form method="post">
<div>
Your IC No: <input type="text" name="ICNo">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should not use `$name` this way, SallyCJ has already written about it.

Comment: ok i have updated my answer